# What is the equivalent of ASP.NET's WebRequest in php?

Tags: php, asp.net, webrequest

What is the equivalent of ASP.NET's WebRequest in php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that would be [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), which can retrieve data from files or remote URLs.

You could also look into using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) if you're interested in retrieving remote resources.

Answer (score 3):

You can to use [`curl`](https://www.php.net/curl).

Some samples here: [Make Yahoo! Web Service REST Calls with PHP](http://developer.yahoo.com/php/howto-reqRestPhp.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add that the file() function can work with URLs too:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.

HTTP, HTTPS are both soported but using these functions you're generating only GET request.

I'd also go curl for the whole package.